# Bind DropDownList t Datatable Column inside DataGrid Control

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, datagrid, dropdownbox

i got `DataGrid` Control that get its Data From `DataTable` inside this DataGrid i want to bound `DropDownList` Control with its related data in DataTable

```
DropDownList commentDrop = (DropDownList)packageCommentDataGrid.FindControl("commentDrop");
       commentDrop.DataSource = dt;
        commentDrop.DataTextField = dt.Columns["CommentString"][0];
        commentDrop.DataValueField = dt.Columns["CommentP"][0];
```

and the ItemDataBound Event will be like this :

```
protected void packageCommentDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DropDownList commentDrop = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("commentDrop");

    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly this is what you'll want to do.

**First:**
You will have to convert the `GridView` column that has the `DropDownList` to `TemplateField`. Make sure the `DropDownList` is inside the `<TemplateField><ItemTemplate><DropDownList id="" runat="server" /></ItemTemplate></TemplateField>`.

**Second:**
Create the `Gridview.RowDataBound` event handler in you code behind. Then inside this method do the following:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells["Column Name / Index here"].FindControl("commentDrop");
    ddl.DataSource = dt;
    ddl.DataTextField = "Column Name";
    ddl.DataValueField = "Column Name";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: actually im using `DataGrid` Control Not `DataGridView`

Comment: Yes I know, but the GridView is the successor of the DataGrid and is easier to work with. Which Dotnet framework are you using? [Before you use the DataGrid control, consider using the GridView control instead. The GridView control, which was introduced in the .NET Framework version 2.0, is the successor to the DataGrid control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx)

Comment: Then I would really suggest to you to use the GridView instead of the DataGrid. But if you intend to stay with the DataGrid, then I'm Afraid this answer will be of little help to you. [See the difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx)

Comment: i got you i will check this out :) Thanks buddy